# Add Ordinal Date

Tags: .net, vb.net

Im trying to add an ordinal date using a public function as per below

```
 Public Function AddOrdinal(ByVal num As Integer) As String

    Dim ordinaldate As String

    Select Case (num Mod 100)
        Case 11 To 13
            Return num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Select Case num Mod 10
        Case 1
            Return num.ToString() & "st"
        Case 2
            Return num.ToString() & "nd"
        Case 3
            Return num.ToString() & "rd"
        Case Else
            Return num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    ordinaldate = Format(Date.Today, "dd") & AddOrdinal() & Format(Date.Today, "MMMM YYYY")

End Function
```

But im getting an error message:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'num' of 'Public Function AddOrdinal(num As Interger) As String'.

Im confused because num has been specififed, but i must be missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your are not coding in VBScript.

Comment: This is not [tag:vbscript], have tagged it more appropriately please [edit] and add any further information.

Comment: `AddOrdinal()` is causing the error. If you want to call your function recursively like this (although I'm not sure _why_ you are trying do to this, it's unclear, it looks to me like you'll get infinite recursion) then you need to provide an input value for `num` in the call to that function

Comment: What is this part supposed to do? `& AddOrdinal() &` ? (I know what `&` does in this case, I'm asking about the purpose of the call to `AddOrdinal`)

Comment: On another sub it open a particular file that has a date as part of the name. The date is todays date but is ordinal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `AddOrdinal()`, in the following statement, it thinks you are trying to call the method recursively:

```
ordinaldate = Format(Date.Today, "dd") & AddOrdinal() & Format(Date.Today, "MMMM YYYY")
```

Since you aren't passing it any parameters, and it requires the `num As Integer` parameter, it gives you that compile error.

In older versions of VB, before the `Return` statement was added, it was not uncommon to reference the return value in that way (though it was never recommended because it could accidentally cause unintended recursion if you weren't careful).  But, in VB.NET, when you return the value by using the `Return` statement, it immediately exits the method, which is obviously not what you are intending to do in this code.  You need to change it so that it holds onto the formatted string in a variable, use that variable at the bottom of the method, and then only return after it's all done:

```
Public Function AddOrdinal(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    Dim ordinalDay As String
    Select Case (num Mod 100)
        Case 11 To 13
            ordinalDay = num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Select Case num Mod 10
        Case 1
            ordinalDay = num.ToString() & "st"
        Case 2
            ordinalDay = num.ToString() & "nd"
        Case 3
            ordinalDay = num.ToString() & "rd"
        Case Else
            ordinalDay = num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Return Format(Date.Today, "dd") & ordinalDay & Format(Date.Today, "MMMM YYYY")
End Function
```

However, there's still a problem with the code.  It still doesn't really make any sense.  It's trying to do two different things at the same time.  It looks like two different methods were mashed together in one.  One method was to take a number as a parameter, and return the formatted ordinal version of the number.  The other was to return the current date as a string (using the ordinal format for the day).  `AddOrdinal` seems like an odd name for either of those methods.  So, you could do all of it in one method, like this:

```
Public Function FormatToday() As String
    Dim today As Date = Date.Today
    Dim day As Integer = today.Day
    Dim ordinalDay As String
    Select Case (day Mod 100)
        Case 11 To 13
            ordinalDay = day.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Select Case day Mod 10
        Case 1
            ordinalDay = day.ToString() & "st"
        Case 2
            ordinalDay = day.ToString() & "nd"
        Case 3
            ordinalDay = day.ToString() & "rd"
        Case Else
            ordinalDay = day.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Return $"{ordinalDay} {today:MMMM} {today:yyyy}"
End Function
```

But, it would probably behoove you to separate the concerns by splitting it up into separate steps:

```
Public Function FormatToday() As String
    Return FormatDate(Date.Today)
End Function

Public Function FormatDate(value As Date) As String
    Dim ordinalDay As String = FormatOrdinal(value.Day)
    Return $"{ordinalDay} {value:MMMM} {value:yyyy}"
End Function

Public Function FormatOrdinal(num As Integer) As String
    Select Case (num Mod 100)
        Case 11 To 13
            Return num.ToString() & "th"
    End Select
    Select Case num Mod 10
        Case 1
            Return num & "st"
        Case 2
            Return num & "nd"
        Case 3
            Return num & "rd"
        Case Else
            Return num & "th"
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy response. This is great, but I'm unable to call the function in another sub. I get the same error message.

Comment: @HulkSmash93 Ok.  I see.  I updated my answer to address the larger problem.

Comment: Thank you again for your help with this. Im getting a character not valid on the $. Is this to notify it as string? I've tried using different notifiers but its not working.

Comment: That's called an [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings).  It's a relatively new addition to the language, so if you are using an older version of the IDE or compiler, that won't work.  Instead, use `ordinalDay & " " & value.ToString("MMMM") & " " & value.ToString("yyyy")`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for being patient with me and adding some teachable lessons :)

Answer (score 0):

Do try this, my is an improvement to steven answer.
Reason begin, there is no way to make the th and nd a supscript so I have to seperate them and type it out.

```
Public Function InsertDate(dateVal As Date)
    Dim myMY        As String
    Dim mOrdinalVal As String
    mOrdinalVal = FormatOrdinal(Format(dateVal, "d"))
    myMY = Format(dateVal, "MMMM yyyy")
    Selection.Font.name = "Cambria"
    Selection.Font.Superscript = False
    Selection.TypeText (Format(dateVal, "d"))
    Selection.Font.Superscript = True
    Selection.TypeText (mOrdinalVal)
    Selection.Font.Superscript = False
    Selection.TypeText (" " & myMY)
End Function
```